# How can we best start a thread of Lion tips/tricks/workarounds?

Tags: discussion

Now that Lion is out, would be great to have a wiki-type thread to track best hidden tips/tricks/tweaks for Lion.  Curious if this is a good topic for AD, or if I should take it to Quora instead ;)

Previously it would have been a Community Wiki, but I see that feature is now gone.  (right?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - started one here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18677/mac-os-x-lion-10-7-x-only-hidden-features-tips-tricks and flagged it for moderator attention

Answer (score 3):

Community Wiki is still available, but it has to be activated by a moderator. My suggestion would be to model the question after [Mac OS X hidden features and nice tips & tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks) and flag your question for moderator attention requesting it to be wikified.

Answer (score 1):

I would say make two.

One for workarounds (where people are looking to change things - urgently looking for an answer to a specific issue)

One for tips / tricks (where people browse for hints, ideas, learning)

yes you can learn from other's problems, many workarounds can be in essence tips or tricks - but I think making it more narrow increases the chance that the answers will track a useful theme...

(there - that ought to be my 2 cents worth)